# Failing to find area under a curve/integrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm trying to calculate the are under a curve and no matter what integration method I use I get many errors and the integral can't be calculated. I feel this should not be the case because I'm indeed able to plot the curve, just not calculate it's area. The plot looks like:
[image]

But when I try to obtain the integral I get a long list of errors:
[image]

The code to replicate all this is a bit long, here it is:

```
    σA = 0.2;
σX = 0.4;
fBar = 0.015;
sD = 0.13;
sS = 0.2;
ρ := 
  0.2;                          (* Subjective discount rate  *)
α := -2;                                 (* Relative Risk \
aversion is := 1 - α  *)
lev = 1;                                 (* Leverage*)                \

ϕ = 95/100;
η = 1;
fA = fBar;
gA = (σX^2 (σX^2 (1 - ϕ) + \
σA^2))/(σX^2 + σA^2);
 gB = (σX^2 σA^2)/(σX^2 + σA^2);
λA := 
  1/2;                         (* Lagrange multiplier for Agent A's \
budget constraint at date 0  *)
λB := 
  1/2;                         (* Lagrange multiplier for Agent B's \
budget constraint at date 0  *)
ω0 = ((1/λA)^((1/(
  1 - α)))) /((1/λA)^(1/(
   1 - α)) + ((η λB)/λA)^(1/(
   1 - α)));

γA1[t_] := γA1[t] = 1/(  
   t (1/sD^2 + ϕ^2/sS^2) + 1/gA);
γB1[t_] := γB1[t] = sD^2/ (t + sD^2/gB);
    HF1[fA_, t_, u_, ε_] := 
  HF1[fA, t, u, ε] = 
   Exp[-(((t - 
        u) ε (sD^2 (2 fA + (-1 + ε) sD^2) \
sS^2 + gA (t (-1 + ε) ϕ^2 sD^4 + 2 fA t sS^2 + 
           sD^2 (2 fA t ϕ^2 + (-t + u ε) sS^2))))/(
     2 (sD^2 sS^2 + t gA (ϕ^2 sD^2 + sS^2))))];

Off[InterpolatingFunction::dmval]
Hg1[gHat_, t0_, u0_, ϵ_, x0_] := 
  Module[{x = x0, u = u0, t = t0},
   PDEC := - 2 HC[
       p] (γB1[-p + u]/sD^2 - ( 
        x (γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u]) )/sD^2) + ( (
      x (x - 1))/(2 sD^2)) + 
     2 HC[p]^2 ((γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u])^2/
        sD^2 + (ϕ^2 (γA1[-p + u])^2)/sS^2) - 
     Derivative[1][HC][p];
   solC = 
    NDSolve[{PDEC == 0, HC[0] == 0}, 
     HC, {p, Re[(u - t) - 0.1], Re[(u - t) + 0.1]}];
   PDEB :=  
    HB[p] (( x (γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u]) )/
        sD^2 - γB1[-p + u]/sD^2 + 
        2 (HC[p] /. 
           solC) ((γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u])^2/
           sD^2 + (ϕ^2 (γA1[-p + u])^2)/sS^2)) + 
     2 (HC[p] /. solC) (γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u] + 
        p (( γA1[-p + 
              u] (γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u]) )/
           sD^2 - (ϕ^2 (γA1[-p + u])^2)/sS^2)) + 
     x (1 + (p γA1[-p + u])/sD^2) - Derivative[1][HB][p];
   solB = 
    NDSolve[{PDEB == 0, HB[0] == 0}, 
     HB, {p, (u - t) - 0.1, (u - t) + 0.1}];
   PDEA1 :=  (HC[p] /. 
        solC) ((γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u])^2/
        sD^2 + (ϕ^2 (γA1[-p + u])^2)/sS^2) - 
     Derivative[1][HA1][p];
   solA1 = 
    NDSolve[{PDEA1 == 0, HA1[0] == 0}, 
     HA1, {p, (u - t) - 0.1, (u - t) + 0.1}];
   PDEA2 :=  (HB[p] /. 
        solB) (1/
         2 ((γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u])^2/
           sD^2 + (ϕ^2 (γA1[-p + u])^2)/
           sS^2) + γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u] + 
        p (( γA1[-p + 
              u] (γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u]) )/
           sD^2 - (ϕ^2 (γA1[-p + u])^2)/sS^2)) - 
     Derivative[1][HA2][p];
   solA2 = 
    NDSolve[{PDEA2 == 0, HA2[0] == 0}, 
     HA2, {p, (u - t) - 0.1, (u - t) + 0.1}];
   Evaluate[HC[u - t] /. solC] gHat^2 + 
    gHat ϵ Evaluate[
      HB[u - t] /. solB] + ϵ^2 Evaluate[
      HA1[u - t] /. solA1] + Evaluate[HA2[u - t] /. solA2]];

EqPricej1[ω_, gHat_, fA_, t_, u_, j_] := 
  EqPricej1[ω, gHat, fA, t, u, j] =  
   Exp[-ρ (u - t)]  HF1[fA, t, u, α] (ω)^(
    1 - α) Binomial[1 - α, j] (1/ω - 1)^
    j Hg1[gHat, t, u, α, j/(1 - α)];
EquityPrice1[ω_, gHat_, fA_, t_, u_] := 
  EquityPrice1[ω, gHat, fA, t, u] =  
   Sum[EqPricej1[ω, gHat, fA, t, u, j], {j, 0, 1 - α}] ;
Plot[EquityPrice1[ω0, -0.03, fA, 0.1, u], {u, 0.1, 1/8}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `EqPricej1` and `EquityPrice1` functions with the below. Note the restriction on `u` so the function only fires when `u` is numeric. Also note the removal of the memoization terms.

```
EqPricej1[ω_, gHat_, fA_, t_, u_?NumericQ, j_] := 
     Exp[-ρ (u - t)] HF1[fA, t,  u, α] (ω)^(1 - α) 
     Binomial[1 - α, j] (1/ω - 1)^j  Hg1[gHat, t, u, α, j/(1 - α)];

EquityPrice1[ω_, gHat_, fA_, t_, u_?NumericQ] := 
     Sum[EqPricej1[ω, gHat, fA, t, u, j], {j, 0, 1 - α}];
```

Then integrate it, note that your `EquityPrice1` funtion returns a list, so you have to pick off the element of the list.

```
NIntegrate[EquityPrice1[ω0, -0.03, fA, 0.1, u] // First, {u, 1/10, 1/8}]

(*  0.0139377  *)
```

Comment: @Jason B., is there an easy way to properly typeset the posts?

Comment: why certainly, a [browser plugin](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1044/9490) written by one of our own.  That made the greek-character changes and I just added some line breaks so you could see everything at once

Comment: Great! Thank you! it does work! :D :D :D